# Type catch while validating XML

Tags: c#, xml, excel, xsd, linq-to-xml

Working for a tax involved company at the moment trying to parse an extensive Excel document into XML code. Nothing impressive. The problem lies with the developer(s) of the XSD schema used to validate the parsed XML code.

Here is where things get crazy. Obvious differences in programming efficiency are noticed throughout the whole XSD, atleast 2 different developers were involved (the second being french, as he swapped from using english names to french...). Now for the problem. Both developers like to use their own structure in making the XSD Schema, one of them uses 1's & 0's to validate checkboxes, the other one uses checked & unchecked. Very handy since all the vars are a combination of the letter c + 4 numbers..

So here finally comes the question! Since I'm parsing everything from the Excel using Interop into 2 List's, all the empty values are recorded as "". This includes empty checkboxes, empty strings, empty dates.

Is there a possibility to check up which type a node is before it is implemented in the XDocument structure? In this way, I could check if the incoming node is from the checkbox type and make sure it gets it's handled "unchecked" string instead of an empty string which won't validate.

My other solution is hardcoding every single code that is from a checkbox type and running a compare every single time ..

Some code of the xsd to show what we're talking about..:

```
        <xs:element name="c1001" type="checkboxType" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="c1002" type="checkboxType" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="c1062" type="checkboxType" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="c1028" type="checkboxType" minOccurs="0"/>>
        <xs:element name="c1035" type="numeric2Type" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="c1054" type="numeric2Type" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="c1055" type="numeric2Type" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="c1036" type="numeric2Type" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="c1037" type="numeric2Type" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="c1058" type="numeric2Type" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="c1059" type="numeric2Type" minOccurs="0"/>    
        <xs:element name="c1043" type="numeric2Type" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="c1044" type="numeric2Type" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="c1032" type="numeric2Type" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="c1033" type="numeric2Type" minOccurs="0"/>    
        <xs:element name="c1100" type="numericu8D2Type" minOccurs="0"/>
```

Some of the code I'm trying to parse:

```
<c1002>checked</c1002>
<c1250>
  <valeur>227967.29</valeur>
</c1250>
<c1254>345.70</c1254>
<c1255>345.70</c1255>
<c1285>17410.44</c1285>
<c1286>
  <valeur>92583.46</valeur>
</c1286>
<c1287>731.28</c1287>
```

Validation is handled through this snippet of code :

```
 if (!IsValidXmlEx(nParsed,@"E:\Work\Resources\xsds\declaration_inr.xsd"))
            MessageBox.Show(Errors);
            else
            MessageBox.Show("Success");

public bool IsValidXmlEx(XDocument xmlDoc, string strXsdLocation)
    {
        bool bStatus = false;
        try
        {
            // Declare local objects
            XmlReaderSettings rs = new XmlReaderSettings();
            rs.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
            rs.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation | XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
            rs.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(rs_ValidationEventHandler);
            rs.Schemas.Add(null, XmlReader.Create(strXsdLocation));

            using (XmlReader xmlValidatingReader = XmlReader.Create(xmlDoc.CreateReader(), rs))
            { while (xmlValidatingReader.Read()) { } }

            ////Exception if error.
            if (nErrors > 0) { throw new Exception(strErrorMsg); }
            else { bStatus = true; }//Success
        }
        catch (Exception error) { bStatus = false; }

        return bStatus;
    }

 void rs_ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning) strErrorMsg += "WARNING: " + Environment.NewLine;
        else strErrorMsg += "ERROR: " + Environment.NewLine;
        nErrors++;
        strErrorMsg = strErrorMsg + e.Exception.Message + "\r\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the XML you are getting from Excel is completely non-valid with respect to the schema. It looks like Excel is treating all exported values as type string.

If this is what is happening then I would suggest that there really isn't any nice way to deal with this. You either need to:

1. Update your Excel export so that it outputs valid XML (with respect to the schema).
2. Convert your Excel output to another XML instance which can then be validated against the schema (maybe using a xslt), or
3. Do your validation in code or some other way, or
4. Don't validate the output at all.

At any rate, there are no "tricks" that I know of to allow non-valid XML to validate against an XSD.

Sorry this is probably not the answer you were looking for.

**UPDATE**

OK - an XSD schema describes how a XML document should look. It defines the types which are legal in that document. Any XML document to be validated against an XSD schema can be said to be a "schema instance" of that schema.

In your case, the XSD defines a type with a load of fields (c1035, c1036, etc), and their types. Each type in your schema sample above appears to be a custom type, which should be defined elsewhere in the XSD.

However, the "schema-instance", in your case the output from Excel, does not validate.

Let's take as an example the XML output:

```
<c1002>checked</c1002>
```

If we look in the schema snippet, we can see the following:

```
<xs:element name="c1001" type="checkboxType" minOccurs="0"/>
```

What this tells me is that there is a type called *checkboxType* defines somewhere in the schema. This type may be inline in the same schema, or it may be defined in another schema which is referenced by this schema.

Now, *checkboxType* will probably have been defined with a set of allowed values for the data in field *c1002* of any schema-instance document, for example "checked", and "unchecked".

If the value in the field is not "valid" according the type definition then the schema-instance is not valid.

This is what is happening when you run the xsd validation against your xml output, except for every single field. Somewhere, there is data being output which is incorrect according to the type definitions defined in the XSD schema.

As you have not provided any error messages it is not possible to know exactly where this is  failing but according to you comment it's somewhere after the first 50 or 60 fields.

Comment: The Excel output is being parsed into an XDocument; which is being read in again during the validation. The validation is already working  partially, clearing the first 50-60 values since they are actually correct. Once an empty string tries to get validated with a checkBox type, everything goes down the drain.
Afaik, it's a valid xml document..

Comment: It may be a well-formed xml document, but it's not valid according the schema you are trying to validate it against. Which-ever way you cut it, the fact remains that your XML output will not validate against your schema. I have updated my answer with another option.

Comment: I sadly do not understand .. could you give me a single example of how the XML document -should- look?

Comment: How the heck am I supposed to know that? You've provided no information about even what error you are getting. I have updated my answer - please have a look.

Comment: I understand better after consulting another colleague, thank you for your help hugh, I did not mean to abuse your proficiency. Have a nice day.

Comment: No problem - sorry if I came across as harsh ;0